# aframe-physics-extras: collision of dynamic entity with static gltf model

Tags: javascript, game-physics, aframe

I'm trying to catch collision event between a dynamic sphere and a static gltf model. I'm building the gltf entity the following way:

```
    const template = document.createElement('a-entity');
    template.setAttribute('physics-collider', 'ignoreSleep: false');
    template.setAttribute('collision-filter', 'collisionForces: false');
    template.setAttribute('body', 'type:static; shape:hull');
    // add position, scale, url etc
    // ...
    template.addEventListener('collisions', e => {
        // debugger;
    })
```

This code creates an entity, but there is no wire net around it in debug mode and the `collisions` event is not being fired.
For debug purposes I tried different shapes. This creates a cylinder around the entity, but it seems too big. The dynamic shape crosses the cylinder, but the `collisions` event is being fired not always, rather rare.

```
    template.setAttribute('body', 'type:static; shape:cylinder');
```

Then I tried to build the shape manually:

```
    template.setAttribute('body', 'type:static; shape:none');
    template.setAttribute('shape', 'shape: cylinder; height: 5;');
```

In this case I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot read property 'bodyOverlapKeeper' of null at NewComponent.<anonymous> (physics-collider.js:34)`

So now I'm stuck. Could someone advice what I'm doing wrong. I'd like to use the shape of the gltf model itself. I opened it in blender, but it seems okay, I don't understand why `shape:hull` doesn't work.

P. S. : if it matters, I'm using webpack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I was able to implement animated collision mesh for a gltf model.
I used a helper function implemented by @Piotr Adam Milewski [here](https://github.com/gftruj/unnecessary-components/blob/main/src/mesh/Box3Utils.js). See more details about the function in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64787687/6188783) answer.
Any other suggestions to improve performance are appreciated.

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('animated-collision-shape', {
    init: function () {
        this.nodeMap = {};

        this.el.setAttribute('body', 'type: static; shape: none;')

        this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {
            const size = new THREE.Vector3();
            let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.el.object3D);
            box.getSize(size);
            this.offset = new CANNON.Vec3(0, size.y / 2, 0);

            let mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
            mesh.traverse(node => {
                if (node.isSkinnedMesh) {
                    this.skinnedMesh = node;
                    this.nodeMap[node.uuid] = {
                        mesh: node,
                        box: new THREE.Box3()
                    }
                }
            });

            if (!Object.keys(this.nodeMap).length) {
                this.nodeMap[0] = {
                    mesh: this.el.object3D,
                    box: new THREE.Box3()
                };
            }

            this.el.components["body"].shouldUpdateBody = true;
        })
    },

    remove: function () {
        this.removeBoxes();
    },

    tick: (function () {
        const size = new THREE.Vector3();
        let common_box_uuid = null;

        return function tick() {
            if (
                !Object.keys(this.nodeMap).length ||
                !this.el.body) {
                return;
            }

            let combine = this.data.combine === true

            let i = 0;
            for (let uuid in this.nodeMap) {
                // Non - skinned case
                if (!this.nodeMap[uuid].mesh.isSkinnedMesh) {
                    this.nodeMap[uuid].box.setFromObject(this.el.object3D);
                    return;
                }
                // skinned model. Either separate boxes, or combined
                if (common_box_uuid && combine) {
                    utils.SkinnedMeshBBox.expandAABB(this.nodeMap[uuid].mesh, this.nodeMap[common_box_uuid].box);
                } else {
                    utils.SkinnedMeshBBox.getAABB(this.nodeMap[uuid].mesh, this.nodeMap[uuid].box);
                    common_box_uuid = uuid
                }

                if (isFinite(this.nodeMap[common_box_uuid].box.max.x)) {
                    this.nodeMap[common_box_uuid].box.getSize(size);
                    if (this.el.body.shapes[i]) {
                        this.el.body.shapes[i].halfExtents = new CANNON.Vec3(size.x / 2, size.y / 2, size.z / 2);
                        this.el.body.shapes[i].updateConvexPolyhedronRepresentation();
                    } else {
                        let shape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(size.x / 2, size.y / 2, size.z / 2))
                        this.el.body.addShape(shape, this.offset, shape.orientation);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }

            this.el.components["body"].shouldUpdateWireframe = true;
        };
    })()
})
```

Comment: Hi, maybe I'm using it incorrectly ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/udLfo5mh/)), but I think there are two issues:
1) The extended boxes are not interacting with dynamic bodies 2) a rotated model has incorrect box shapes (because its made of an world-aligned bounding box)

Meanwhile I think I've managed to get some results for animated models ([link](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/physics/animated_models.html)) but It's such a mess I'd personally attach colliders to bones (like [here](https://github.com/gftruj/unnecessary-components/tree/main/src/physics))

Comment: I used this [SkinnedMeshBBox](https://github.com/gftruj/webzamples/blob/d7d1f68c460846470039e397d7edeef419230a26/aframe/models/components.js). I didn't compare them to be honest. In your fiddle it looks like the bboxes only getting extended during the animation and are not "collapsing" back. And collision events work for me, although I haven't created a test fiddle, will try to do it. Thanks for your examples btw, will them as well, but how can I get the bone names?

Comment: You can check them up in blender (or name them in blender). If the model is complicated, you can check out what are the node names while traversing the mesh, to know what you're looking for :)

Comment: hi @PiotrAdamMilewski, your code works like a charm, thanks :) Now I'm thinking about bones rotation. Is there a way to place a box along a bone? What I mean is a box should repeat the bone movements. Now it's always parallel the floor and it's center is bound to one of the bone vertices I guess.

Comment: Not only should it copy the rotation, but I think it should enable doing things like [these](https://github.com/gftruj/unnecessary-components/issues/1)

Comment: Something like [this](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/physics/bone_collider.html) ?

Comment: feel free to star the repo if you like it ;)

Answer (score 1):

**0. using setAttribute**

`setAttribute` won't handle a list like:

```
template.setAttribute('body', 'type:static; shape:none');
```

[Rather](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/entity.html#setattribute-componentname-value-propertyvalue-clobber) provide an object of the new attributes:

```
element.setAttribute("name", {
  "property 1": "value 1",
  "property 2": "value 2"
});
```

---

**1. dynamic body/shape set-up**

That being said, you can create a custom static cylinder like this:

```
element.setAttribute("body", {
   "type": "static",
   "shape": "none"
})

element.setAttribute("shape__cylinder", {
   'shape': 'cylinder',
   "height": 1.5,
   "radiusTop": 0.1,
   "radiusBottom": 0.2
})
```

check it out in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/vpg4dw2b/5/)

---

**2. dynamic shape for models**

As for creating a dynamic shape for a gltf model. Personally i had no luck using `cannon`, although it worked well with the `ammo` driver. On the other hand I've had a huge FPS drop (on ~older mobile devices), so If possible, try using simple collision meshes for performance sake.

You can get a bounding box of a skinned model with a simple function [I made](https://github.com/gftruj/unnecessary-components/blob/main/src/lib/Box3Utils.js):

```
let box = new THREE.Box3()
THREE.Box3Utils.fromSkinnedMesh(skinnedMesh, box);
// box should be the bounding box of the skinned mesh
```

**3. animated models**

I'd highly recommend creating simple collision shapes and attaching them to a certain bone in the model. A starting point could be [this component](https://github.com/gftruj/unnecessary-components/tree/main/src/physics):

```
<a-gltf-model bone-collider="bone: boneName; halfExtents: 0.15 0.15 0.15">
```

---

The bounding box approach will be very complicated since:

- You'd have to compute a bounding box for an non-rotated mesh
- apply the rotation to the result (bounding boxes are world-aligned)
- update the body on each tick, or even remove the shape and add it anew ([source](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/issues/270))

You can see both approaches in [this example](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/physics/animated_models.html)

Comment: thanks for your response. I managed to create a composite mesh from simple parts. But my gltf model has an animation. Is there a way I can "move" the parts of collision mesh along with animated model?

Comment: @NikitaFedorov do you have a bone to which you can attach a collision mesh?

Comment: The model position is fixed, so I guess I can create some anchor, if that's what you mean.