# AFrame: position offset units when adding new Object3D to the current one

Tags: javascript, aframe

I'm trying to add an Object3D to my gltf model and place it above the model. I'm doing it the following way:

```
this.el.addEventListener('model-loaded', () => {

            this.bar = new MyCustomObject3D();

            const size = new THREE.Vector3();
            let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.el.object3D);
            box.getSize(size)
            let height = size.y + 1;

            this.bar.position.set(0, height, 0);
            this.el.setObject3D("bar", this.bar);
            // same result: 
            // this.el.object3D.add(this.bar); 
        })
```

The `height` is 2 and if I placed an element with this position into root (i.e. scene) it would be placed correctly right above the model. But when I add it to the `Object3D` it's being placed somewhere below the model on height ~0.5. Only by multiplying the height by 25 I could achieve the right position.
So how to calculate the exact offset needed to place the new `Object3D` above the model without multiplying it to a random number?

UPDATE:

Adding [reproducible example](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/amused-humorous-moon). Note the width and height I had to pass to GLTF model.

Comment: Tried reproducing, but [seems to be working](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/0khbwamo/2/). Can you upload a minimal example to a [glitch](https://glitch.com/)?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski thanks for your reply, indeed it works for primitives, but doesn't work for models: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/amused-humorous-moon

Comment: Its working with models, but not with skinned ones apparently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of placing objects above a model, would be grabbing its bounding box, and placing an object above it.

In general, it it simple - just like you did it:

```
let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.el.object3D);
box.getSize(size)
let height = size.y + 1;
this.bar.position.set(0, height, 0);
```

But in this case - the bounding box is off. Way off. The minimum is way too low, and the maximum is somewhere in the middle. Why is that? (tldr: check it out [here](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/models/above_head.html))

The cuprit is: **skinning**. The model is transformed by its bones - which is a form of vertex displacement that happens on the GPU (vertex shader), and has nothing to do with the geometry ([source](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/object-bounds-not-updated-with-animation/3749/2)).

Here is some visual aid - the model with its armature:
[image]
And without the armature applied:
[image]

Now we see why the box is off - its corresponding to the bottom picture!
So we need to re-create what the bones are doing to the geometry:

**1. The hard route**

1. You need to take a THREE.Box3.
2. Iterate through each geometry point of the model
3. Apply the bone transform to each point (it is done [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/SkinnedMesh.js#L120-L160) - but not available in a-frame 1.0.4)
4. Expand the THREE.Box3

**2. The easy route**
While looking into this, I've made a utility function `THREE.Box3Utils.fromSkinnedMesh(mesh, box3);` - box3 will be the bounding box of the model **at the time when the function is called**.
The function is a part of [this](https://github.com/gftruj/unnecessary-components) repo.
Its used on [this example](https://gftruj.github.io/webzamples/aframe/models/above_head.html).

Comment: Wow, that's impressive, you also managed to make the box to move along with animation. Can it by any chance be applied to collision shape in aframe-physics-system? Here is the reference to my previous question you helped me with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213030/aframe-physics-extras-collision-of-dynamic-entity-with-static-gltf-model

Comment: As for moving it with the animation - check out the source code, im just doing `THREE.Box3Utils.fromSkinnedMesh(mesh, box3);` on each `tick()`.
As for the physics system, Id try updating the shape by accessing it in `this.el.body`, although I would have to try it first

Comment: @NikitaFedorov I'll let you know if i come up with something :)

Comment: I noticed that you're adding the box to scene, but not to the current object3D. That works for me either simply by using `let box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(this.el.object3D);`